# Output from imploded array not returning first instance (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

So, I have an array which I am combining to create an `INSERT` command. (No sanitizing done yet, just a proof of concept).

`$namedata` is the data for the "Name" field (for example "This Name")
`$refdata` is the data for the "Ref" field (for example "43857368")
`$CatRefData` is my array (for example, '23', '45', '2', '144')

I am formulating it as follows:

```
$inputdata = "'), ('".$namedata."', '".$refdata."', '";
  $data = implode($inputdata, $CatRefData);
  $result = "INSERT INTO `MyTable`('Name', 'Ref', 'Cat_Ref') VALUES ('".$data."')";
```

But the output comes out with the first instance of the array missing any of the additional "non-array" data, like this:

> $result = INSERT INTO `MyTable`('Name', 'Ref', 'Cat_Ref') VALUES
>   ('23'), ('This Name', '43857368', '45'), ('This Name', '43857368',
>   '2'), ('This Name', '43857368', '144')

Can you see - the first instance, where the array value is '23', doesn't have any of the surrounding information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think this doesnt work with implode, so you have do do a foreach to fill your $data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this...

```
$arr = array();

foreach($CatRefData as $d) {
    $arr[] = "('".$namedata."', '".$refdata."', '".$d."')";

}

$data = implode(",",$arr);
```

but you should do some escaping...

Comment: Ah, "foreach"! Thanks - a great solution. Perfect!  (I will be escaping each of the values before they get as far as this formula, but thank you for the advice all the same).

Answer (score 1):

`implode()` only adds the join text BETWEEN values, so if you have:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$newarr = implode('foo', $arr);
```

you'll end up with

```
afoobfooc
```

but you actually need

```
fooafoobfooc
```

That means you have to "prime" your query with the "join" text first:

```
$result = "INSERT INTO `MyTable`('Name', 'Ref', 'Cat_Ref') VALUES ('$inputData"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with implode only.

Try using it with [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
, something like this:

```
$CatRefData = [ '23', '45', '2', '144'];
function surrounding($n)
{
     return "('something', '123', '".$n."')";
}
echo implode(", ",array_map("surrounding", $CatRefData));
```